# Laravel 6 - Best way to reuse existing request validators within others request validators

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

Let's say there are two Laravel API resources `Book` and `Author`, each with some rules for validating the `store` request.

Then, there's a third API resource where API consumers can post a certain thing along with a `Book` and an `Author`. That is to say, the `store` request must accept a `Book` object, an `Author` object, and a third `FooBar` object:

```
// sample POST body
{
  "book": {...book object...},
  "author": {...author object...},
  "foobar": {...foobar object...}
}
```

In the `FooBarRequest` validation `rules()`, would make sense to reuse `BookRequest::rules()` and `AuthorRequest::rules()`, but it's not working:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class FooBarRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        $bookRules = BookRequest::$validationRules;
        $authorRules = AuthorRequest::$validationRules;

        return [
            'book' => $bookRules,
            'authorRules' => $authorRules,
            'foobar' => 'required|...some rules...'
        ];
    }
}
```

Perhaps using Laravel's [custom rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#using-rule-objects), but it doesn't help so much since the `passes` method must return a boolean (i.e. we should re-write all the validation logic for each attribute).

Is there any elegant/official way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer out on [Laracasts:](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/reuse-validation-rules-in-form-request-in-another-form-request)

If you want to use the same validation rules in multiple places, perhaps use a trait and then use it in multiple form requests. So for book rules:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait BookValidationTrait
{
    protected function bookRules ()
    {
        return [
            'book_input_1' => 'your rules here',
            'book_input_2' => 'your rules here',
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Then for author rules:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait AuthorValidationTrait
{
    protected function authorRules ()
    {
        return [
            'author_input_1' => 'your rules here',
            'author_input_2' => 'your rules here',
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Then in your book form request class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Traits\BookValidationTrait;

class BookRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use BookValidationTrait;

    public function rules()
    {
        return $this->bookRules();
    }
}
```

In your author form request class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Traits\AuthorValidationTrait;

class AuthorRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use AuthorValidationTrait;

    public function rules()
    {
        return $this->authorRules();
    }
}
```

And finally, in your FooBar form request class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Traits\BookValidationTrait;
use App\Traits\AuthorValidationTrait;

class FooBarRequest extends FormRequest
{
    use BookValidationTrait, AuthorValidationTrait;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array_merge(
            $this->bookRules(),
            $this->authorRules(),
            [
                'foobar_input_1' => 'your rules here',
                'foobar_input_2' => 'your rules here',
                ...
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it looks like that could work.

Comment: Merging rules is not working as the `FooBarRequest` will receive a payload with an attribute for each entity. The question is indeed how to reuse `bookRules` and `authorRules` in a nested attribute of the request body.

Answer (score 1):

`book` and `title` attributes will fall under the [Validating Nested Array Input](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-nested-array-input) rules.

For example, if you have:

```
$bookRules = ['title' => 'required', 'body' => 'text'];
$authorRules = ['name' => 'required'];
```

You want the rules to be like:

```
[
    'book.title' => 'required',
    'book.body' => 'text',
    'author.name' => 'required',
    'foobar' => 'required|...some rules...',
];
```

Assuming `BookRequest::$validationRules` and `AuthorRequest::$validationRules` already return what you want, you need to do the following to get there:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class FooBarRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        $bookRules = BookRequest::$validationRules;
        $authorRules = AuthorRequest::$validationRules;

        return array_merge(
            $this->getNestedArrayRules($bookRules, 'book'),
            $this->getNestedArrayRules($authorRules, 'author'),
            ['foobar' => 'required|...some rules...']
        );
    }

    protected function getNestedArrayRules($rules, $key) {
        return array_combine(
            array_map(fn ($attribute) =>  "$key.$attribute", array_keys($rules)), 
            $rules
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I see one way how to solve this problem, but also I'd like to demonstrate an example that can help in easier cases when you need to validate just one entity, for example, book:

Use BookRequest through DI:

```
class FooBarRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(BookRequest $request)
    {
        return [
            'foobar' => 'required|...some rules...'
        ];
    }
}
```

Specifically for your case, I advise you to use [the rules](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules). You can use them in FooBarRequest, and also reuse them in other FormRequest classes:

```
class FooBarRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'book' => [new BookValidationRule()],
            'authorRules' => [new AuthorValidationRule()],
            'foobar' => 'required|...some rules...'
        ];
    }
}
```